# How to prove ~($\forall$x Q(x)) is logically equivalent to $\exists$x(~Q(x)) using natural deduction for first order logic

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, natural-deduction

I am thinking of assuming Q(x1) and then deriving to reach to a contradiction but I have not been able to do so.

Comment: Could you give us some more background? For instance, in my book, this is the _definition_ of $\forall$.

Comment: here $\forall$ stand for "for all" x that belong to domain of discourse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Hint*

1st part, using [Natural Deduction](https://www.iep.utm.edu/nat-ded/#H4) :

1) $\exists x \lnot Qx$ --- premise

2) $\forall x Qx$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot Qa$ --- assumed [b] from 1) by $\exists$-elim

4) $Qa$ --- from 2) by $\forall$-elim

5) $\bot$ --- contradiction : from 3) and 4)

6) $\bot$ --- from 1) and 3) and 5) by $\exists$-elim, discharging [b]

> 7) $\lnot \forall x Qx$ --- from 2) and 6) by $\lnot$-intro, discharging [a].

---

2nd part :  quite similar, using *Double Negation*.

1) $\lnot \forall x Qx$ --- premise

2) $\lnot \exists x \lnot Qx$ --- assumed [a]

3) $\lnot Qx$ --- assumed [b]

*and so on* ...

Comment: Thanks. Can you also show for other way round?